MapKit flashing screen each time a zoom level is changed with custom map tiles workaround?
I am using MKTileOverlays to display a custom map. I have .canReplaceMapContent set to true since I don't need or want to display the standard map tiles. But every time the zoom level changes, the entire screen flashes gray (the background color of the MKMapView). I thought if I could set the map view background to transparent, I could place a screenshot behind the map view before the view is zoomed and remove it after the view is rendered. The view snapshot would also have to zoom in with the view, but it seems doable.
Through layer sniffing, I found that the gray background (RGB 21,21,21) comes from a VKMapView layer in this hierarchy:
Layer: CALayer
  Layer: CALayer
    Layer: _MKMapLayerHostingLayer
      Layer: VKMapView  // Has background color RGB(21,21,21)
        Layer: CAMetalLayer

I've tried several approaches to modify this, such as setting the VKMapView layer's background to .clear:
if let firstLayer = layer.sublayers?.first,
   let secondLayer = firstLayer.sublayers?.first,
   let thirdLayer = secondLayer.sublayers?.first,
   let fourthLayer = thirdLayer.sublayers?.first {
    
    fourthLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    fourthLayer.isOpaque = false
    
    if let metalLayer = fourthLayer.sublayers?.first as? CAMetalLayer {
        metalLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        metalLayer.isOpaque = false
        metalLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm_srgb
    }
}

Setting the layer's opacity to 0 confirms it is the correct layer, but something else must be setting the background color later in the view life cycle. Of course, with the alpha set to 0, it won't display any map content.
I tried setting these properties at various lifecycle points (init, viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, etc.), but nothing worked.
Ideally, I'd like MapKit to either:
• Keep showing the previous zoom level's tiles until new ones are ready
• Allow the background to be transparent or customizable
• Or provide some other way to prevent the flash
Has anyone managed a work around to the flashing? It just destroys what would be a nice user experience. I filed a bug for this many months ago with Feedback Assistant FB13989005 but has been ignored.
The Apple sample code "MapKitOverlays" recreates the following issues.
The "Load tiles from Server" and "Customized Tile Loading" examples flicker, even after the tiles have been loaded and cached. I verified that the issue occurs even when URLSession is using the cached tiles by adding the delegate function urlSession(_ , task, didFinishCollecting metrics:).
When using local tiles, the entire screen flashes blank for a frame or so every time the zoom level changes one level, even after they’ve been loaded. I’m using the attached following for the overlay. Note it only flashes at each zoom level only when the flyover map modes are not used.
For unknown reasons, using the flyover modes is much better. The problem is that when using flyover modes with .canReplaceContent is set to true now causes a severe bug that causes the label text to wander great distances from the features they label. Apple has acknowledged but said they can't say if or when it will ever be fixed.
extension MapViewController {
    
    func configureLocalTileOverlay() {

        let tileDirectoryName = "localTiles"
        guard let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath else { return }
        let localPath = "file://\(resourcePath)/\(tileDirectoryName)/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        let tileOverlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: localPath)
    
        tileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
    
        tileOverlay.tileSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        tileOverlay.minimumZ = 2
        tileOverlay.maximumZ = 14
    
        mapView.addOverlay(tileOverlay, level: .aboveRoads)
    }
}


Wow, that is a thorough dive! It sounds like you've isolated two Apple bugs (the layer flashing which you've filed, and the meandering labels which you might have filed too). Did you get anywhere by using a Tech Support Incident? A completely different approach, depending on your budget and userbase, could be to switch over to Mapbox, which has nice API for adding your own custom layers.

Thanks. The Tech Support incident essentially concluded that my bug reports were helpful but they can't say if or ever the issues will be addressed. Thanks for the suggestion but Mapbox isn't an option for a number of reasons.
